# library not found for -lncurses on OS X terminal

Tags: c++, macos, ubuntu, clang, llvm

I am a rookie developer on OS X.  When I compile a project with a Makefile, there is an error that I can not solve.
But I can successfully run this project on Ubuntu16.04, but not when I move it to Mac.

This is the terminal print:

```
currychen-MC1:llvm-clang-iMac currychen$ make
g++ -I/usr/include -fno-rtti -O0  -g `/Users/currychen/llvm/llvm3.8-binaries/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags` -I/Users/currychen/llvm/tools/clang/include -I/Users/currychen/llvm/llvm3.8-binaries/tools/clang/include src_clang/rewritersample.cp -lclangAST -lclangAnalysis -lclangBasic -lclangDriver -lclangEdit -lclangFrontend -lclangFrontendTool -lclangLex -lclangParse -lclangSema -lclangEdit -lclangASTMatchers -lclangRewrite -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore -lclangSerialization -lclangToolingCore -lclangTooling  `/Users/currychen/llvm/llvm3.8-binaries/bin/llvm-config --ldflags --libs --system-libs` -o build/rewritersample
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk'
ld: library not found for -lcurses
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [build/rewritersample] Error 1"
```

and my Makefile is

```
LLVM_SRC_PATH := /Users/currychen/llvm
LLVM_BUILD_PATH := /Users/currychen/llvm/llvm3.8-binaries
LLVM_BIN_PATH := $(LLVM_BUILD_PATH)/bin

CXX := g++ -I/usr/include
CXXFLAGS := -fno-rtti -O0  -g

LLVM_CXXFLAGS := `$(LLVM_BIN_PATH)/llvm-config --cxxflags`
LLVM_LDFLAGS := `$(LLVM_BIN_PATH)/llvm-config --ldflags --libs --system-libs`
LLVM_LDFLAGS_NOLIBS := `$(LLVM_BIN_PATH)/llvm-config --ldflags`


CLANG_INCLUDES := \
    -I$(LLVM_SRC_PATH)/tools/clang/include \
        -I$(LLVM_BUILD_PATH)/tools/clang/include

CLANG_LIBS := \
    -lclangAST \
        -lclangAnalysis \
        -lclangBasic \
        -lclangDriver \
        -lclangEdit \
        -lclangFrontend \
        -lclangFrontendTool \
        -lclangLex \
        -lclangParse \
        -lclangSema \
        -lclangEdit \
        -lclangASTMatchers \
        -lclangRewrite \
        -lclangRewriteFrontend \
        -lclangStaticAnalyzerFrontend \
        -lclangStaticAnalyzerCheckers \
        -lclangStaticAnalyzerCore \
        -lclangSerialization \
        -lclangToolingCore \
        -lclangTooling 

SRC_CLANG_DIR := src_clang
BUILDDIR := build

$(BUILDDIR)/rewritersample: $(SRC_CLANG_DIR)/rewritersample.cp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LLVM_CXXFLAGS) $(CLANG_INCLUDES) $^ $(CLANG_LIBS) $(LLVM_LDFLAGS) -o $@


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)/*
```

Comment: On my Mac, I can run `ls /usr/lib/lib*curse*` and get the list: `/usr/lib/libcurses.dylib`, `/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib`, `/usr/lib/libncurses.5.dylib`, `/usr/lib/libncurses.dylib`.  What do you get?

Comment: Add a `-v` to your compile line and see what flags are really getting used, then figure out why `/usr/lib` isn't on the list. OS X comes with curses by default.

Comment: when I run ls /usr/lib/lib*curse* , I can get the list /usr/lib/libcurses.dylib /usr/lib/libncurses.5.dylib
/usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib /usr/lib/libncurses.dylib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jonathan Leffler and @Carl Norum.
Add a -v is very helpful for me to see what flags are really getting used.
And finally I also add a -L in g++ to make the compiler know where the lib in.
So , if you have installed the libXXX, you should appoint the dir to make the compiler know.